# Flex3: Is it Possible to Embed only a Few Letters from a Font?

Tags: apache-flex, embedded-fonts

Is there a way to embed only a few letters from a font instead of embedding the whole thing? I only need say 7 capital letters from a font. Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you CAN do that.  You just specify which characters or character ranges you want to embed from the font and only those characters get embedded:  http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_07.html

Comment: Hi Wade, Thank you for the link. Very cool. I must have missed that in searching Adobe's help.

Comment: yup go for fonts in flash, n use the characteers u want to embed, thr is Glyph range thr

Comment: @Ankur Sharma: Not sure what your point is here, can you clarify?

Comment: hi wade, ma point is same as wht u have answered, only embed, needed glyphs or there ranges, thats it, the link wht u have given is correct, but we can do this in flash as well, i normally, if have to go for it, then do the same thing in flash, so the prepared font swf is already equipped with the embedded fonts,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, but you can create your own fort and include only the needed chars you want to use.